# How to convert mongo shell code to java code using document and mongo aggregation

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How can I convert this code to java? How to use aggregation framework in java ? Can anyone please help me out...

My java code:

```
Document update = new Document("$project",new Document("TOTAL_EMPLOYEE_SALARY",new Document("$sum","$employees.EMP_SALARY")));
 AggregationOutput output = coll.aggregate(update); // throwing some error in eclipse
```

My mongo shell code :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "TOTAL_EMPLOYEE_SALARY": {
           "$sum": "$employees.EMP_SALARY"
        }
    }}
])
```

Comment: Could you add the error to question?

Comment: Actually eclipse is not allowing me to write this line:AggregationOutput output = coll.aggregate(update); .It is asking for cast argument 'update' to List<? extends BSON>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So use a `List`:

```
List<Document> pipeline = Arrays.<Document>asList(
    new Document("$project",
        new Document("TOTAL_EMPLOYEE_SALARY",new Document("$sum","$employees.EMP_SALARY"))
    )
);

AggregationOutput output = coll.aggregate(pipeline);
```